# Clonable class hierarchy and unique_ptr

Tags: c++, inheritance, clone, abstract-class, unique-ptr

I have a problem with clonable abstract classes and unique pointers. Suppose I have the following clonable abstract base class

```
class Base
{ 
    public:
        virtual void doSomething()=0;
        virtual std::unique_ptr<Base> clone() const=0;
}
```

and a derived abstract class which provides an additional method

```
class Derived : public Base
{ 
    public:
        virtual void doSomething()=0;
        virtual void doSomethingMore()=0;
        virtual std::unique_ptr<Base> clone() const=0;
}
```

This allows to define new classes that store a polymorphic object of the Base hierarchy by composition. For instance

```
class Composed
{ 
    public:
        Composed(Base const &base_) : basePtr(base_.clone()) {}

    private:
        std::unique_ptr<Base> basePtr;
}
```

In this way I should be able to store an object of type Derived in Composed, without slicing the methods that Derived adds wrt Base. However, I would like to define another object that stores a polymorphic object that inherits from Derived, considering it as an object of type Derived. Using the same structure as above

```
class ComposedDerived
{ 
    public:
        ComposedDerived(Derived const &derived_) : derivedPtr(derived_.clone()) {}

    private:
        std::unique_ptr<Derived> derivedPtr;
}
```

Clearly, I get a compilation error since the clone method of Derived returns a `std::unique_ptr<Base>`. On the other hand, if I change the definition of Derived as follows

```
class Derived : public Base
{ 
    public:
        virtual void doSomething()=0;
        virtual void doSomethingMore()=0;
        virtual std::unique_ptr<Derived> clone() const=0;
}
```

In this case, the compiler gives the following error: `invalid covariant return type for ‘virtual std::unique_ptr<Derived> Derived::clone() const`.

Is there a way for the compiler to understand that `std::unique_ptr<Derived>` can in fact be used as a `std::unique_ptr<Base>` through polymorphism and not argue about the return type of the Derived class `clone` method?

Comment: How about `derivedPtr(static_cast<Derived*>(derived_.clone().release()))`?

Comment: This seems a smart way to do it. Could you please explain the `.release()`? From what I understand, `derived_.clone()` returns a `std::unique_ptr<Base>` object. `.release()` let this unique_ptr release the ownership of the `Derived` object which has been created in the heap and returns a `Base*` object. Finally I cast this pointer to a `Derived*` pointer which is used to initialize `derivedPtr`.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 3):

Use the NVI (non-virtual interface idiom) for the `clone()` method as follows:

```
class Base
{ 
    public:
        virtual void doSomething()=0;

        std::unique_ptr<Base> clone() const {
            return cloneImpl();
        }

    private:
        virtual std::unique_ptr<Base> cloneImpl() const=0;
};

class Derived : public Base
{ 
    public:
        virtual void doSomething()=0;
        virtual void doSomethingMore()=0;

        std::unique_ptr<Derived> clone() const {
            return std::unique_ptr<Derived>(static_cast<Derived*>(cloneImpl().release()));
        }
};
```

You can even add more safety and convenience of "overriding" the `clone()` method in the subclasses as follows:

```
class Base
{ 
    public:
        virtual void doSomething()=0;

        std::unique_ptr<Base> clone() const {
            return checkedClone<Base>();
        }

    protected:
        template<class T>
        std::unique_ptr<T> checkedClone() const {
            auto p = cloneImpl();
            assert(typeid(*p) == typeid(*this) && "subclass doesn't properly override cloneImpl()");
            assert(nullptr != dynamic_cast<T*>(p.get()));
            return std::unique_ptr<T>(static_cast<T*>(p.release()));
        }

    private:
        virtual std::unique_ptr<Base> cloneImpl() const=0;
};

class Derived : public Base
{ 
    public:
        virtual void doSomething()=0;
        virtual void doSomethingMore()=0;

        std::unique_ptr<Derived> clone() const {
            return checkedClone<Derived>();
        }
};
```

Comment: This is interesting. So if I understand correctly I would simply need to implement `virtual std::unique_ptr<Base> cloneImpl() const` method in the concrete classes inheriting from either `Base` or `Derived`. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. But if you will need to also be able to easily clone an object of the concrete class, then you can also "override" the `clone()` function similar to how it was done in `Derived`.

Comment: So in the `Derived` class I can have at the same time the `std::unique_ptr<Derived> clone() const` method and a `std::unique_ptr<Base> clone() const` method. Is that because the `clone()` method in the `Base` class is no longer abstract so that I can override it?

Comment: Yes, but note that "override" is not a correct term in that case (that's why I had it quoted). Actually `Derived::clone()` hides `Base::clone()` (when access through a `Derived` object).

Answer (score 1):

What about exploiting covariant return:

```
class Base { 
public:
    std::unique_ptr<Base> clone() const {
        return std::unique_ptr<Base>(cloneImpl());
    }
    virtual ~Base();
private:
    virtual Base* cloneImpl() const;
};

class Derived : public Base { 
public:
    std::unique_ptr<Derived> clone() const {
        return std::unique_ptr<Derived>(cloneImpl());
    }
    ~Derived() override;
private:
    // Covariant return:
    Derived* cloneImpl() const override;
};
```

Comment: With this approach, I would have to implement `cloneImpl()` methods in each class inheriting from either `Base` or `Derived`. Is that right? What are the pros and cons wrt to the NVI proposed by @Leon? Thanks for your help

Comment: The pro is that you do not need the static_cast.

Comment: Imagine that in the `Derived` class I wanted to have both a `std::unique_ptr<Base> clone() const` method and a `std::unique_ptr<Derived> clone() const` method. How can I achieve that using this technique?

Comment: Well you do have both of them. However, only the latter is visible. The former is hidden. You can use the second with : foo.Base::clone() is you want to. However, you probably don't really need that as `std::unique_ptr<Derived>` is convertible into `std::unique_ptr<Base>`.

Comment: Great. One last question... in `Derived* cloneImpl() const override`, why do I need the `override` keyword? Is that because the compiler would not be able to distinguish this method from the `virtual Base* cloneImpl() const;` which is inherited from Base? Many thanks